# oracle hierarchical query nocycle and connect by root

Tags: oracle, hierarchical

Can somebody explain use of nocycle and connect by root clauses in hierarchical queries in oracle, also when we dont use 'start with' what is the order  we get the rows, i mean when we don't use 'start with' we get lot many rows, can anybody explain nocycle and connect by root(how is different than start with?) using simple emp table, Thanks for the help

Answer (score 7):

If your data has a loop in it (A -> B -> A -> B ...), Oracle will throw an exception, `ORA-01436: CONNECT BY loop in user data` if you do a hierarchical query. `NOCYCLE` instructs Oracle to return rows even if such a loop exists.

`CONNECT_BY_ROOT` gives you access to the root element, even several layers down in the query. Using the HR schema:

```
select level, employee_id, last_name, manager_id ,
connect_by_root employee_id as root_id
from employees
connect by prior employee_id = manager_id
start with employee_id = 100

     LEVEL EMPLOYEE_ID LAST_NAME                 MANAGER_ID    ROOT_ID
---------- ----------- ------------------------- ---------- ----------
         1         100 King                                        100
         2         101 Kochhar                          100        100
         3         108 Greenberg                        101        100
         4         109 Faviet                           108        100
...
```

Here, you see I started with employee 100 and started finding his employees. The `CONNECT_BY_ROOT` operator gives me access to King's employee_id even four levels down. I was very confused at first by this operator, thinking it meant "connect by the root element" or something. Think of it more like "the root of the CONNECT BY clause."

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for explaining..yes but am still confused as in we can get the root element with 'start with' clause too isn't it? I checked it by using 'start with employee_id = 102' and thought the hierarchy will start with 102 but connect by root will give "100" as the root in this employee hierarchy. However root_id column gives 102, so if we can get root element using 'start with' clause why to use connect_by_root. Also please explain loop again to me :( if A is manager of B then again B is manager of A,? i know its dumb that am not getting it,but please explain, thanks a lot for help!

Comment: Start with lets you define the starting conditions for the recursion (by defining a filter on the nodes that are used as start points for the recursion). CONNECT_BY_ROOT lets you output columns belonging to the start nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is about nocycle use in query.

Suppose we have a simple table 
with r1 and r2 column names and the values for 
first row r1=a,r2=b
and second row r1=b,r2=a
Now we know **a** refers to **b** and **b** refers back to **a** .
Hence there is a loop and if we write a hierarchical query as

**select r1 from table_name
start with r1='a'
connect by  prior r2=r1;**

we get connect by loop **error**

Hence use **nocycle** to **allow** oracle to give results even if loop exists.

Hence the query
**select r1 from table_name
start with r1='a'
connect by nocycle prior r2=r1;**